# I am not able to see git branch name in eclipse. I have import a 4 projects from among them 2 are showing a git repository and 2 are not showing it

Tags: eclipse, git

I am not able to see the branch name in eclipse Mars as I have imported a git projects from my local repository. Among 4 projects 2 are showing a branch name and first 2 do not. From a same branch I have added some code in projects which is showing and send it for merge. When i go inside that branch again projects who is showing branch name is contains the code which i have changed but another project who is not showing branch name not contain code changes which i have done while sending merge.

Answer (score 1):

I expect more information here on how exactly you've imported projects into eclipse here.

Generally following are the steps: Try these:

1. git clone your repository first into a local folder
2. Use Import.. from File menu
3. Then under Git folder, select projects from git
4. Choose existing local repository and Mention the folder that you fetched in step 1. Eclipse will read the git structure if correct folder name is given.
5. Then import it as General Project by selecting your concerned folder. This step is imported. You should select a folder that you want to keep it parent in your eclipse project. Also use General project.
6. You can update it to Maven project after the above steps are completed.